# Convert decimal to base 4 assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

How to convert integers in an array that are in decimal to base 4 (signed and unsigned)?

Comment: Decimal being text, or binary? :) Can you do it in pseudocode or C? Where do you get stuck? Show what you got. Also, look around SO, plenty of base conversion examples.

Comment: text. for example: 23 should be converted to 113

Comment: I looked all over the net, couldnt find nothing about that. i dont need the whole code, just the idea. i dont know even how to start

Comment: Convert your text to binary first by multiplying by 10 and adding the digits in a loop. Really dozens of examples for that. From binary to base 4 it's then trivial, just output every 2 bits as a digit (0-3). Use shifting and masking.

Comment: and for unsigned numbers?

Comment: For signed numbers just detect the leading `-` sign and output it too.

Comment: @Jester
can you detail more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the algorithm of dividing the number by the desired base repeatedly until the quotient is zero, using the remainders as the final result in reverse order, example :

```
       QUOTIENTS OF EACH DIVISION
            ▼     ▼     ▼
     23÷4 = 5÷4 = 1÷4 = 0
      3     1     1
      ▲     ▲     ▲
 REMAINDERS OF EACH DIVISION
```

The remainders are the digits in the new base (in reverse order) : "113".

Your code will require two blocks :

- One block to make the divisions until the quotient is zero, in this block you store the remainders in stack (push). Each quotient **is the dividend** of the next division.
- Another block to pop out the remainders and store them in a string. Remainders will be extracted in reverse order.

**Edit :** in case of negative numbers, the sign must be detected first, if the sign is negative it is necessary to get the absolute value of the number, example :

```
abs $t1, $t1
```

The sign must be re-applied to the result at the end (if necessary).

Comment: And for signed numbers?

Comment: @Edmond, just edited my answer to include the possibility of negative numbers.