# Decimal to base 4 convertion assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to convert integers in an array from decimal to base 4 using divisions by 4.

The code i wrote is:

```
li $t0, 0   #array index - initialize to zero 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg4 #msg4 = The numbers in the array as signed numbers in base 4 are:
syscall

base4Signed:
lb $t1, array($t0)   #load array integer, t0 is the index of the array
li $t4, 4            #use for divide
li $t6, 0            #counter of stack
beq $t0, 10, end

division:
div $t1, $t4         #divide the integer by 4
mflo $t3             #save the quotient in t3
mfhi $t5             #save the reminder in t5
addi $sp, $sp, -1    #push stack
sb $t5, 0($sp)       #store reminder
addi $t6, $t6, 1     #counter + 1
move $t1, $t3        #use t3 = quotient for next division
beqz $t3, print      #quotient = 0
j division

print:
li $v0, 1
la $a0, 0($sp)
syscall
addi $sp, $sp, 1
addi $t6, $t6, -1
bnez $t6, print
addi $t0, $t0, 1
beqz $t6, base4Signed

end:
```

I get some strange result.

This array: 100,0,120,6-,2,45,67,89,12-,23

should be converted to: 1210,0,1320,12-,2,231,1003,1121,30-,113 (signed)

and to: 113,3332,231,1003,1121,30,2130,0,1320,12 (unsigned)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to convert to text.

Comment: @Jester 
How should i do it?

Comment: It might be easier to use a right-shift by 2 instead of using the actual DIV instruction.  It will be dramatically faster on any real hardware.  Rule of thumb: never use DIV with a compile-time-constant power of 2.  You can get remainder with an AND with `3` to zero everything but the low 2 bits.

Comment: Perhaps this link will answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065452/convert-decimal-to-base-4-assembly-mips

Answer (score 0):

You should change the second step on "print" to load byte instead of load address
you should write:
lb $a0, 0($sp)